# Is it possible to use email and phone number to authentication in Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am looking for a way in swift to make user sign up with his/her phone number then add his/her email and password.
But when user logs in , he/she logs in only with email and password.

The phone number is only for security reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can link an email and password to a user account that is created via phone authentication but Firebase Auth does not enforce 2 factor authentication the next time the user signs in. The user is able to log in with either (email/password or phone) without requiring both.
You will need to implement your own custom solution for this.
Please file a request via Firebase support or the official Firebase Google Group for 2 factor auth.

If you wish to just verify the phone number and link it to the account but not require it next sign-in, you can after you create user with email and password, ask the user for the phone number, call:

`[[FIRPhoneAuthProvider provider] verifyPhoneNumber:phoneNumber ...]`

which resolves with a verificationID. You then initialize a phone auth credential after getting the SMS code:

`FIRPhoneAuthCredential *credential =
    [[FIRPhoneAuthProvider provider] credentialWithVerificationID:verificationID  verificationCode:verificationCode];`

Finally you call:
`[[[FIRAuth auth] currentUser] linkWithCredential:credential]`

on the currentUser using the phone credential. This will add that phone number to the email/password user. You can consider it verified. The next time they sign in with email/password you can access that via user.phoneNumber.

Comment: Actually i just want the user to verify his phone number for the first time after he enter his email and pass. After that he use only his email and password

Comment: Ok, i updated my answer. Hopefully it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @bojeil i am getting error like this please see URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922710/firebase-phone-number-authentication-error