# Firebase Phone number authentication Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am Using Firebase phone number login authentication All things are perfect

1) Provisioning profile

2) certificate

3) Signing methods Enable

4) Project setting with .12 file

5) everything should perfect

Issue 
When I send mobile number for the OTP using thins method using this code

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"+919428936703";

[[FIRPhoneAuthProvider provider]
 verifyPhoneNumber:phoneNumber
 completion:^(NSString * verificationID,
              NSError * error) {

     NSLog(@"VARIFICATION CODE %@", verificationID);
     NSLog(@"Error %@", error);

     if (!error){


     }else{

     }
 }];
```

Also get call methods

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Pass device token to auth.
    [[FIRAuth auth] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRAuthAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    NSLog(@"DATA OF AUTH %@", [FIRAuth auth]);

    if ([[FIRAuth auth] canHandleNotification:notification]) {

        NSLog(@"Handle by Firebase ");

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
        return;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"NOT HANDLE BY FIREBASE %@", notification);
    }
}
```

but then after getting a crash with this error log

```
-[__NSCFString setFir_authPhoneNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166388b0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not linking your app with `-ObjC` linker flag, which is part of the instructions for [Integrate without CocoaPods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).

`setFir_authPhoneNumber:` is implemented as a [category](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/31a2acb7497eaaeae38b7ceb17edcab09d7f2866/Firebase/Auth/Source/AuthProviders/Phone/NSString%2BFIRAuth.m), thus `-ObjC` linker flag must be used or the compiled `.o` from the library won't be linked into your app binary.